# Java Challenge in LinkedList

Tags: java, collections, linked-list

Question 4:
Given an integer array, convert it into a linked list with each node containing one sequence.

```
Sample Input : [1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20, 23, 30,31,32]
Sample Linked List : [1] -> [3,4,5] -> [8,9] -> [11] -> [13,14,15,16]->[20]->[23]->[30,31,32]
```

The question may seems to be easy but it's bit difficult to answer.Can anyone write code for the above in Java without using `Collection` or `LinkedList` ?

Below is the code for detecting sequence (which might help).

```
class Sequence {
    public static String detectSequence(int seq[]) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < seq.length - 1; i++) {
            if (seq[i + 1] == seq[i] + 1) {
                result += seq[i] + " ";
                if (i != seq.length - 2) {
                    if (seq[i + 1] != seq[i + 2] - 1) {
                        result += seq[i + 1];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                result += " ";
            }
        }
        if (seq[seq.length - 1] == seq[seq.length - 2] + 1) {
            result += seq[seq.length - 1];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
class Question1 {
    public static void main(String[] cla) {
        int seqArray[] = {
            4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 4, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 10, 11, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4
        };
        String res = Sequence.detectSequence(seqArray);
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to give you a start...

```
public YourLinkedList splitToSequences(int[] array) {
    YourLinkedList list = new YourLinkedList();

    if(array.length > 0) {
        YourSequence sequence = new YourSequence();
        int currentNumber;
        int lastNumber = array[0];
        sequence.add(lastNumber);

        for(int index = 1; index < array.length; index++) {
            currentNumber = array[index];
            if(currentNumber != lastNumber + 1) { // curentNumber breaks the sequence
                list.add(sequence);               // save the old sequence to list 
                sequence = new YourSequence();    // and start a new one
            }
            sequence.add(currentNumber);
        }

        list.add(sequence);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Now go and figure out your linked list and sequence classes and do the printing stuff...

A minimalistic implementation of a linked list

```
public class MyLinkedList<T1> {
    private MyLinkedListItem<T1> first = null;
    private MyLinkedListItem<T1> last = null;

    public MyLinkedList() {
    }

    public void add(T1 item) {
        MyLinkedListItem<T1> newItem = new MyLinkedListItem<T1>(item);
        if (first == null) {
            first = newItem;
        } else {
            last.setNext(newItem);
        }
        last = newItem;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        if(first != null) {
            MyLinkedListItem<T1> current = first;

            while(current.hasNext()) {
                buffer.append(current.toString());
                buffer.append(" -> ");
                current = current.getNext();
            }

            buffer.append(current.toString());
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }

    private class MyLinkedListItem<T2> {
        private T2 data;
        private MyLinkedListItem<T2> next = null;

        public MyLinkedListItem(T2 data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return next != null;
        }

        public MyLinkedListItem<T2> getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(MyLinkedListItem<T2> next) {
            this.next = next;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return data.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's what i meant when i said you need to figure out your classes. the above code was just to give you a direction.

Answer (score 0):

First the code that splits the array in several chunks can be written using an Iterator to avoid to mix this algorithm with the code that creates the linked list.
Then there is a way to implement a simple linked list in a functional fashion (so the whole list is immutable).

Obviously, this code is unreadable but fun !

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class LinkedConsecutiveInts {
  private static Iterator<int[]> iterator(int[] array) {
    return new Iterator<int[]>() {
      private int index;

      @Override
      public boolean hasNext() {
       return index < array.length;
      }

      @Override
      public int[] next() {
        int first = array[index];
        int value = first + 1;
        int i = 1;
        for(; index + i < array.length && array[index + i] == value++; i++) {
          // empty
        }
        index += i;
        return IntStream.range(first, first + i).toArray();
      }
    };
  }

  interface Seq<T> {
    void forEach(Consumer<? super T> consumer);

    default <U> Seq<U> map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper) {
      return consumer -> forEach(e -> consumer.accept(mapper.apply(e)));
    }

    default String joining(String separator) {
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      forEach(e -> builder.append(e).append(separator));
      if (builder.length() != 0) {
        builder.setLength(builder.length() - separator.length());
      }
      return builder.toString();
    }

    static <T> Seq<T> from(Iterator<? extends T> it) {
      if (!it.hasNext()) {
        return consumer -> { /* empty */ };
      }
      T element = it.next();
      Seq<T> next = from(it);
      return consumer -> { consumer.accept(element); next.forEach(consumer); };
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] values = { 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20, 23, 30, 31, 32 };

    Seq<int[]> seq = Seq.from(iterator(values)); 
    System.out.println(seq.map(Arrays::toString).joining(" -> "));
  }
}
```